# WP-JSON: Cross Origin Resource Sharing Vulnerability?

Tags: cors

I am testing the security of a webpage owned by the company I work for. I noticed that an arbitrary origin is accepted. In the screenshot below, you'll see that I added that example origin which was reflected in the response accordingly.

I am not the admin of this web page nor am I logged into it. I am testing it remotely like an external user. However, If I was logged in, I'm wondering if I could see cookies/API Keys etc in the response? Is this a vulnerability that needs to be fixed or is this just normal, secure word press behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IF* the page in question is secured - that is, if its content is not equally public to all users without any authentication or authorization required - then this is technically fine. It's still a *bad idea* - that exact scenario is what `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is for, and there's no justification whatsoever for the other Access-Control-Allow-... headers - but it wouldn't be a vulnerability.

In all other situations - which is probably most of them - this is a security disaster.

Doing this effectively turns off more than half of the same-origin policy for the page. Any arbitrary script on any website can now see the content of the page *as viewed by a different user*, make requests with any verb, and probably also bypass any CSRF protection.

Directly accessing cookies remains one of the few things an attacker can't do here. Another is modifying the page content; the attacker still could not edit the contents of a window or iframe open to the vulnerable site, and thereby inject scripts. The last is accessing site-specific storage that a script running on that site could access (local storage, session storage, indexed DB, etc.); this *might* impede an attacker, if the site is using Bearer tokens instead of cookies (but then, why set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`?). However, most other SOP protections can either now be worked around, or are outright disabled, by such CORS configurations.

For example, not accessing the cookies doesn't matter much. Suppose we have a user (victim) who is logged into this vulnerable site, and also browses a site I control (or at least I control a script on). I can, in effect, remote control their browser now with regard to the vulnerable site! I can make arbitrary requests (as the user), and I can see the responses. If I want, I can load them in my own browser and view the site as the victim would see it. For so long as the victim is on any webpage I control (that is, one where I control a script on it), I can use their browser and their session to do approximately anything with the vulnerable site that the victim could themselves do.

Now, it's possible that only public pages have this disaster of a policy set, and if you actually tried to post or edit a page, access an admin console, or otherwise take any action that requires authorization, the server would reject it. You should test that, if at all possible. However, this sort of very clumsy policy (combined with certain priors about the security of WP in general) makes me suspect that this was copy-pasted as a global set of headers to add to every response, or at least every CORS response, across the site. In other words, it is at least strongly *indicative* of a severe vulnerability, one not quite so bad as XSS but significantly worse than CSRF.

---

As an aside, that joke of a `Strict-Transport-Security` header makes me suspect that this site just isn't intended for public exposure at all yet. That's the sort of HSTS policy you set when you want to test if your site is compatible with HSTS, without breaking things for too long if not. It provides no actual security, which is pretty bad for a header whose only purpose is to increase security.